# How to fix : "WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer." in android avd?

Tags: android, opengl-es

So i get an warning when i start the avd :

> "WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software
>   renderer."

i had found answers in internet but none of them worked for me, so headache !

**Detail** :

Window Xp SP3 x86.

ADT Bundle for Windows from Google (lastest version): http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.
Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same and could not cope fast, cheers...it says: "Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it" I have unchecked "Host GPU", now it can run the emulator somehow

Answer (score 0):

It might sound like a lame answer, but in my case it was simply a matter of needing to update my Geforce drivers to fix this issue.  If you find the emulator has been working fine, then suddenly refuses to start when set to use the host GPU, ensure that you check this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve it as below.

I think OpenGL did not work on my Windows 10 OS. I fixed it easily:

1. Open android studio
2. Select tools from the header tabs
3. Select AVD Manager
4. Click on the "Create Virtual Device..." button and in the "Verify Configuration" step, find "Graphics" property and set it to "Software".
5. Complete all steps without any manipulation.
6. Start your machine and enjoy!